# $E(X+Y)$ of independent bivariate distribution.

Tags: statistics

Let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables with
joint density function $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \frac{1}{100}e^{\frac{-(x+y)}{10}}$, $x>0$, $y>0$. Calculate the expected value $E(X+Y)$

Given I know the distribution is independent, what would be the correct way 
to calculate $E(X+Y)$?.

Answer (score 2):

Given that you know that $X$ and $Y$ are independent, $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = f_X(x)f_Y(y)$.

So, for $x,y > 0$, you have $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \dfrac{1}{100}e^{-\tfrac{x+y}{10}} = \dfrac{1}{10}e^{-\tfrac{x}{10}} \cdot \dfrac{1}{10}e^{-\tfrac{y}{10}} = f_X(x) \cdot f_Y(y)$.

Now that you have the PDFs of $X$ and $Y$, so you can simply use linearity of expectation:

$\mathbb{E}[X+Y] = \mathbb{E}[X]+\mathbb{E}[Y] = \displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}xf_X(x)\,dx + \int_{0}^{\infty}yf_Y(y)\,dy = \cdots$.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\E}{\operatorname{E}}$
$\E(X+Y) = \E(X)+\E(Y)$ regardless of whether $X$ and $Y$ are independent or not.

In this case, you can use independence to find the marginal density of $X$:
$$
\text{constant}\cdot e^{-x/10}\cdot e^{-y/10}
$$
Since $y$ is constant as a function of $x$, this is $(\text{constant}\cdot e^{-x/10})$.  Given that, you can find $\E(X)$, and $\E(Y)$ can be found similarly.